# Docker + Nginx deleted folder issue

Tags: php, nginx, joomla, docker

I have been trying to setup this docker image: https://github.com/Muraad/joomla-docker

In practice it has worked great. Docker builds the image, I can run it in a container, and I can link Joomla with another Docker container running mysql. Joomla is hosted by Nginx and PHP5-FPM.

The problem starts when I delete the installation folder. While the container is running, the deletion causes no issues and the site operates as expected. Once I reboot the Docker host however, the site gives the following error:

> An error occurred.
>
> Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable. Please
>   try again later.
>
> If you are the system administrator of this resource then you should
>   check the error log for details.
>
> Faithfully yours, nginx.

The error is only shown if I delete a folder from the volume. If the folder remains present on the disk, even after Joomla setup with file changes, the site works fine. Once I delete the Installation folder however this error is all I see. There are no useful logs for Nginx/php5-fpm or Joomla. What I find interesting is the Nginx error log at /var/log/nginx/error_log is seemingly corrupt, when I try and read it with vim it says it is not a valid file. The folder being deleted resides nested in a VOLUME from the Dockerfile.

```
VOLUME ["/var/www/vhosts"]
```

I am stumped as to wether this is a Docker issue or an Nginx issue. I can't determine what would be the root cause and why this only happens after a reboot. I did a test and instead of deleting the installation folder, I deleted the images folder. This had the same result leading to the conclusion that it isn't Joomla related.

Comment: Instead of using editor to read the log file try `less /var/log/nginx/error_log` and give us the error message if you receive any.

Comment: It says: `WARNING: terminal is not fully functional` then proceeds to open but the file is blank.

Comment: On another container, I've let it sit overnight with this error and in the morning it was gone. In the meantime I have rebuilt several containers and done various work inside of them. I don't see the connection or understand why the error would go away. Deleting another folder then rebooting the host causes the error to come back.

Comment: I've found that deleting just a file does not produce this issue. Only folder deletion..

Comment: However, running `chmod -R 000 installation/` effectively reproduces the problem without even rebooting the host. This is so confusing and I'm not finding anything on Google.

Comment: That `installation` folder is part of what? docker?

Comment: It is part of Joomla, but nested inside of a volume mount from Docker. Deleting or removing permissions of any file inside the mount causes Nginx fits.